# Remove the 'multiple selection' from my listbox in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have an address lookup function on my website which when the postcode is entered and is valid a `listbox` is displayed displaying all the address which match the postcode entered, the problem i have is that i am able to select multiple address but i haven't added the 'multiple' attribute anywhere so don't know why it's displaying can someone please point out the obvious to me.

My listbox code is:

```
<%: Html.ListBox("AddressList_Dropdown" + Model.Name, ( IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ) addresses, new { @class = "form-control", @size = "4" })%>
```

I have tried adding it in the HTML attributes as defined for the listbox:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ListBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes);
```

The user should only be allowed to select on option from the address list returned.

I am using MVC3, HTML5 if that helps.

Comment: What is the HTML rendered output for the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's *exactly* what [a `ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listbox.aspx) does:

> Returns a select element that lets users select **one or more** items.

If you want the user to select only a single element, use [a `DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492948.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to try a dropdown list instead and decided to go with that option as it works just the same.